# Why are my forms not returning field errors?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Recently I upgraded my django server. Going from 1.2 to a new version.  The forms exhibit a strange behavior.  When a field is left blank the whole page simply refreshes, rather than showing errors like I remember.  What could cause this?  What ought I do to fix it?

```
{%extends "baseAUTH.html" %}
    {% block title  %}
    {{ title }}
    {% endblock %}


    {% block content %}
{% load adminmedia %}

<script type="text/javascript">
window.__admin_media_prefix__ = "{% filter escapejs %}{% admin_media_prefix %}{% endfilter %}";
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/core.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/forms.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/base.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/global.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/widgets.css"/>

{{ form.media }}


    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>

    {% if form.errors %}
        <p style="color: red;">
            Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.
        </p>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <table valign=TOP>
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Have you tried checking and outputting form.non_field_errors too?

Comment: You'll need to show the code of the view.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  I reverted some changes back and found the point where I broke it.  In the following function I tried to abstract

```
def FormToEmail(request, token, title, subject, message, reciever, attachlist):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        sender = AddSender(request)
        reciever.append(sender)

        form = token(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            mail = EmailMessage(subject, message, sender, reciever)

            if len(attachlist) > 0:
                for item in attachlist:
                    if form.cleaned_data[item]:
                        temp = request.FILES[item]
                        mail.attach(temp.name, temp.read(), \
                            temp.content_type)

            return SendIt(request, mail)
```

Here to

```
    else:
        form = token()
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render_to_response('FormTemplate.html',  \
        {'form': form, 'title' : title},  \
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/Webtemplate/accounts/login')
```

here.  Into

```
return RenderFormForAuth(request, token(), title)
```

with the function defined as

```
def RenderFormForAuth(request, form, title):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render_to_response('FormTemplate.html',  \
        {'form': form, 'title' : title},  \
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/Webtemplate/accounts/login')
```

which broke everything.  (I can paste the whole function/ how it's called if need be, but seems like a waste of space.)

Does anyone know why this wouldn't work?

Comment: can you show the complete code of the function that is handling the view. It is not clear whether you are populating the POST data into form or not